# Android set webview width to match its content width

Tags: javascript, android, css, webview, width

I have a `RecyclerView` whose itemview is a `WebView`, the pages (in fact, just a few words with html tags) I'm gonna show in this `WebView` has different width, is there any way to make this `WebView` to match its content width?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
}

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);  
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```